# Como eu preservo o menu ao chamar uma nova página pelo getX?

Tags: flutter, dart

Estou construindo um app em flutter, nele eu tenho um sideBar e tenho várias opções, como abaixo:
[image]

Minha vontade e ao clicar por exemplo em vendas, ao em vez de fechar o sideBar e abrir uma nova tela, queria que a mesma aparecesse ao lado como está o dashbord.

código da página principal:

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

final AppbarController _appBarController = Get.put(AppbarController());
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    key: _appBarController.scaffoldKey,
    drawer: SideMenu(),
    body: SafeArea(
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          if (Responsive.isDesktop(context))
            Expanded(flex: 1, child: SideMenu()),
          Expanded(flex: 5, child: DashboardPage())
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
}
```

alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como é uma construção futura, baseada em algo que vai mudar, você vai precisar colocar seu objeto ou homepage "App" para StatefulWidget. Já para alterar a parte principal sem alterar o sidebar, você pode criar um child `Builder class`. Como o nome é bem intuitivo, você vai criar algo baseado em uma variável, caso queira ou não! Vou te dar um exemplo lógico: vamos supor que dentro de seu objeto App, tenha uma variável que se chame "Page", essa variável é uma string, onde você pode armazenar o nome de cada pagina que deseja que seja carregada onde se encontra esse "Dashboard", dessa forma, você pode partir para o Build e fazer um teste lógico de if e if else, ou um switch (quem escolhe é você). Logo em seguida é só colocar um setState que sua página vai carregar no lugar do dashboard.

Seu código ficaria assim:

```
  final AppbarController _appBarController = Get.put(AppbarController());

  String actualPage = 'DashBoard';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _appBarController.scaffoldKey,
      drawer: SideMenu(),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            if (Responsive.isDesktop(context))
              Expanded(flex: 1, child: SideMenu(fnPage: setActualPage)),
            Expanded(
              flex: 5,
              child: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                if (actualPage == "DashBoard") {
                  return DashboardPage();
                } else if (actualPage == "Vendas") {
                  return VendasPage();
                } else {
                  return Container();
                }
              }),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  
  void setActualPage(String page){
    setState(() {
      actualPage = page;
    });
  }
}
```

Fiz uma função de callback ou set, que você precisa passar como parâmetro para dentro do seu objeto `SideMenu`, dessa forma quando alguém clicar no TextField dentro do `SideMenu`, a nova página será carregada na sua página principal.

Comment: Maravilha muito obrigado pela resposta, com base no que você respondeu, eu criei um controller, aonde eu recebo o item direto do sideMenu ao ser clicado, faço a logica e envio para View, atualizando com GetBuild o parte que precisa ser renderizada.